# Is there a way to limit the size in memory that w3wp (IIS) can get to?

Tags: iis, performance

Is there a way to limit the size in memory that w3wp (IIS) can get to?

I am running windows 7 x64 with IIS.
As I debug my web app, the memory taken up by IIS goes up to 4GB.

Is there a way to limit this effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the application pool for the web app to recycle when it reaches a certain memory size. Check out the help file for IIS manager to decide whether you need to set it for Virtual or Private memory. You'll most likely want to set the Private Memory setting (typically used for memory leaks) - the recommendation in the help is 60% of your systems physical memory.